# xslt using c# function and used for a hyperlink

Tags: xslt

I have some xslt that uses a c# function to get a string, im calling it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="myClass:GetContent('key')" />
```

it works fine.

but i now need to use it part of a url.

```
<a href="{concat('/',select='myClass:GetContent('key')','/mysite.com')}">
```

i cant get it working...
any ideas what to do?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so (the "select" is just the way of specifying the query; with the abbreviated attribute syntax ("`{query}`") you just specify the query directly)

```
<a href="{concat('/',myClass:GetContent('key'),'/mysite.com')}">
```

Or alternatively:

```
<a href="/{myClass:GetContent('key')}/mysite.com">
```